# How to display multiple panels from an array in a frame using a loop

Tags: java, arrays, layout, jframe, jpanel

I have never been very good at using java graphical interfaces. I am creating a program that will create an array of "contact" and display them to a frame. I can add, delete, and sort the array correctly. I just cannot get it to display to the screen right.  I have run into several variations of incorrect displaying. No matter what I do I cannot seem to get the "contact" to display right. I mean that when this program is run a jframe should appear, containing 4 contacts with a picture and text information. then the user can delete one of the contacts and the program should show a new alphabetically sorted list without the deleted contact.

The issue im having is getting my contacts to display in a jframe. When i run the program the contacts appear but only if in the main method i call my show function every time a new contact is added. otherwise the jframe only shows the last contact added until the program is told which contact to delete. then the jframe displays too many contacts.

Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. I apologize for my bad formatting. this is the first time I have used this site.

```
/*
blake yacavone
advanced programming
project 1
*/

import java.util.Scanner;

public class project1Tester
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      contactArrayList list = new contactArrayList();

      contact beatle1 = new contact("Paul", 1284, "Beverly Hills", "California", 90209, "paul.jpg", "vocals");
      list.addContact(beatle1);
      list.showContacts();

      contact beatle2 = new contact("Pete", 1284, "Beverly Hills", "California", 90209, "pete.jpg", "drummer");
      list.addContact(beatle2);
      list.showContacts();

      contact beatle3 = new contact("John",  1284, "Beverly Hills", "California", 90209, "john.jpg", "vocals");
      list.addContact(beatle3);
      list.showContacts();

      contact beatle4 = new contact("George", 1284, "Beverly Hills", "California", 90209, "george.jpg", "vocals");
      list.addContact(beatle4);
      list.showContacts();

      System.out.println("please enter the identification number of the contact you would like deleted ");
      list.delete(input.nextInt());
      list.showContacts();

      contact beatle5 = new contact("Ringo", 1284, "Beverly Hills", "California", 90209, "ringo.jpg", "drummer");
      list.addContact(beatle5);
      list.showContacts();

      list.sort();
      list.showContacts();
   }
}



/*
blake yacavone
advanced programming
project 1
*/
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class contactArrayList extends JFrame
{
   public contact[] contactList;                                           //declares an array of contacts
   JFrame contactViewer;                                                   //creates a frame to hold my panel
   JPanel contactGrid;                                                     //creates a panel to hold my contact information
   int contactCount = 1;                                                   //keeps track of / assigns ID numbers to each contact that is created

   contactArrayList()                                                      //constructor for a contact array list
   {
      this.contactList = new contact[0];                                   //creates an array of contacts of inital size 0

      this.contactViewer = new contactListFrame();
      contactViewer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      this.contactGrid = new JPanel();
        contactGrid.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

      contactViewer.add(contactGrid);
      contactViewer.setVisible(true);
   }

   int checkList(String name)                                              //walks through the array checking for a contact of a specified name
   {
      if(contactList.length == 1)                                          //if the length of the contact list is one than its empty and an element should be added
      {
         return 1;
      }

      for(int i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++)
      {
         if(name.equals(contactList[i].getName()))
         {
            return 0;
         }
      }
      return 1;
   }

   void addContact(contact person)
   {                                                                       //calls check and if check returns true it adds the contact to the contactList
      if ( (checkList(person.getName())) > 0 )
      {
         resize(1);                                                        //calls resize method to increase the size of the array
         person.setID(contactCount++);                                     //gives the contact their id number
         contactList[contactList.length-1] = person;                       //adds the contact to the end of the array
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("ERROR, the requested contact is already in the list");
      }

   }

   void delete(int ID)                                                     //deletes a contact specified by name
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < contactList.length-1; i++)                        //runs through the array searching for the specified name
      {
         if(ID == contactList[i].getID())                                  //if the ID i was given matches the one im looking at in the 
         {                                                                 //contact list AND i+1 does not equal the end of the array, 
            contact temp = contactList[i];                                 //swap the entry marked for deletion with the next entry
            contactList[i] = contactList[i+1];                             //in the array until entry marked for deletion is at the end
            contactList[i+1] = temp;
         }
      }
      resize(-1);
   }

   void resize(int direction)
   {
      if(direction > 0)                                                    //if direction is a positive number increase the array size
      {
         contact[] tempList = new contact[contactList.length + 1];         //creates a temporary contact list array

         for(int i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++)                       //runs through the contact list array and copies its data into the temp list
         {
            tempList[i] = contactList[i];
         }

         contactList = new contact[contactList.length + 1];                //re initalizes contact list with a new size

         for(int i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++)                       //runs through the temp array and copies its data into the new bigger contact list
         {
            contactList[i] = tempList[i];
         }
      }
      else if(direction < 0)                                               //if direction is a negative number decrease the array size
      {
         contact[] tempList = new contact[contactList.length];             //creates a temporary contact list array

         for(int i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++)                       //runs through the contact list array and copies its data into the temp list
         {
            tempList[i] = contactList[i];
         }

         contactList = new contact[contactList.length - 1];                //re initalizes contact list with a new size

         for(int i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++)                       //runs through the contact list array and copies its data into the temp list
         {
            contactList[i] = tempList[i];
         }
      }
   }

   void sort()
   {

      for(int i = 0; i < contactList.length-1; i++)
      {
         for(int j = 1; j < contactList.length; j++)
         {
            if( (contactList[i].getName().charAt(0)) < (contactList[j].getName().charAt(0)) );
            {
               contact temp = contactList[i];
               contactList[i] = contactList[j];
               contactList[j] = temp;
            }
         }
      }
   }



   void showContacts()
   {
      JLabel contactInfo = new JLabel();


      for(int i = 0; i < contactList.length; i ++)
      {
         contactInfo.setText( getText(contactList[i]) );

         ImageIcon photo = new ImageIcon(getPicture(contactList[i]));
         contactInfo.setIcon(photo);

         contactGrid.add(contactInfo);
         contactGrid.setVisible(true);
      }

      contactViewer.add(contactGrid);
      //contactViewer.pack();
      contactViewer.setVisible(true);
   }









   String getPicture(contact person)
   {
      return (person.getPicture());
   }

   int getID(contact person)
   {
      return (person.getID());
   }

   String getName(contact person)
   {
      return (person.getName());
   }

   int getAddress(contact person)
   {
      return (person.getAddress());
   }

   String getCity(contact person)
   {
      return (person.getCity());
   }

   String getState(contact person)
   {
      return (person.getState());
   }

   int getZipCode(contact person)
   {
      return (person.getZipCode());
   }

   String getComment(contact person)
   {
      return (person.getComment());
   }

   String getText(contact person)
   {
      String text = Integer.toString(getID(person)) + " \n " + getName(person) + " \n " + Integer.toString(getAddress(person)) + " \n " + getCity(person) + " \n " + getState(person) + " \n " + Integer.toString(getZipCode(person)) + " \n " + getComment(person);
      return(text);
   }
}










    /* 
   Blake yacavone
*/
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;



public class contactListFrame extends JFrame
{
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;
    private static final int FRAME_OFFSET = 15;


    public contactListFrame()
    {
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
   }

}







    /*
blake yacavone
advanced programming
project 1
*/

public class contact
{
   private int ID = 0;
   private String name;
   private int address;
   private String city;
   private String state;
   private int zipCode;
   private String picture;//picture is a string with the file name of the picture to be displayed with the Contact.
   private String comment;

   public contact(String name, int address, String city, String state, int zipCode, String picture,String comment)
   {
       this.name = name;
       this.address = address;
       this.city = city;
       this.state = state;
       this.zipCode = zipCode;
       this.picture = picture;
       this.comment = comment;
   }

   public contact()
   {
      this.name = "problem name";
      this.address = 1134;
      this.city = "problem city";
      this.state = "problem state";
      this.zipCode = 1134;
      this.picture = "problem picture";
      this.comment = "problem comment";
   }

   public void setID(int ID)
   {
      this.ID = ID;
   }
   public String getName()
   {
      return this.name;
   }

   public int getAddress()
   {
      return this.address;
   }

   public String getCity()
   {
      return this.city;
   }

   public String getState()
   {
      return this.state;
   }

   public int getZipCode()
   {
      return this.zipCode;
   }

   public String getPicture()
   {
      return this.picture;
   }

   public String getComment()
   {
      return this.comment;
   }

   public int getID()
   {
      return this.ID;
   }
}
```

Comment: firstly You don't have a main method write your main method and inside it create an instance from your class

Comment: What does _"display right"_ mean?

Comment: And use Java naming convention. Class names start with capital letters

Comment: @ElhadiMamoun: in 'project1Tester' class

Comment: And don't mix GUI with console.

Comment: If your `ContactArrayList` extends a `JFrame`, you don't need to create a new one (re: `contactViewer`). Just have the `contactArrayList` add components to itself (ie `this.add` etc).

Comment: Try printing contactList.length in the showContacts() once.

Answer (score 0):

Only displaying on Screen?

I have putted  all your classes on your runnable class(which has the main method) and converted  classes to static classes to access that static method

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class project1Tester
{
 public static class contactListFrame extends JFrame
{
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;
    private static final int FRAME_OFFSET = 15;


    public contactListFrame()
    {
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
   }

}








  public static class contact
{
   private int ID = 0;
   private String name;
   private int address;
   private String city;
   private String state;
   private int zipCode;
   private String picture;//picture is a string with the file name of the picture to be displayed with the Contact.
   private String comment;

   public contact(String name, int address, String city, String state, int zipCode, String picture,String comment)
   {
       this.name = name;
       this.address = address;
       this.city = city;
       this.state = state;
       this.zipCode = zipCode;
       this.picture = picture;
       this.comment = comment;
   }

   public  contact()
   {
      this.name = "problem name";
      this.address = 1134;
      this.city = "problem city";
      this.state = "problem state";
      this.zipCode = 1134;
      this.picture = "problem picture";
      this.comment = "problem comment";
   }

   public void setID(int ID)
   {
      this.ID = ID;
   }
   public String getName()
   {
      return this.name;
   }

   public int getAddress()
   {
      return this.address;
   }

   public String getCity()
   {
      return this.city;
   }

   public String getState()
   {
      return this.state;
   }

   public int getZipCode()
   {
      return this.zipCode;
   }

   public String getPicture()
   {
      return this.picture;
   }

   public String getComment()
   {
      return this.comment;
   }

   public int getID()
   {
      return this.ID;
   }
}
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      contactArrayList list = new contactArrayList();

      contact beatle1 = new contact("Paul", 1284, "Beverly Hills", "California", 90209, "paul.jpg", "vocals");
      list.addContact(beatle1);
      list.showContacts();

      contact beatle2 = new contact("Pete", 1284, "Beverly Hills", "California", 90209, "pete.jpg", "drummer");
      list.addContact(beatle2);
      list.showContacts();

      contact beatle3 = new contact("John",  1284, "Beverly Hills", "California", 90209, "john.jpg", "vocals");
      list.addContact(beatle3);
      list.showContacts();

      contact beatle4 = new contact("George", 1284, "Beverly Hills", "California", 90209, "george.jpg", "vocals");
      list.addContact(beatle4);
      list.showContacts();

      System.out.println("please enter the identification number of the contact you would like deleted ");
      list.delete(input.nextInt());
      list.showContacts();

      contact beatle5 = new contact("Ringo", 1284, "Beverly Hills", "California", 90209, "ringo.jpg", "drummer");
      list.addContact(beatle5);
      list.showContacts();

      list.sort();
      list.showContacts();
   }
   public static class contactArrayList extends JFrame
{
   public contact[] contactList;                                           //declares an array of contacts
   JFrame contactViewer;                                                   //creates a frame to hold my panel
   JPanel contactGrid;                                                     //creates a panel to hold my contact information
   int contactCount = 1;                                                   //keeps track of / assigns ID numbers to each contact that is created

   contactArrayList()                                                      //constructor for a contact array list
   {
      this.contactList = new contact[0];                                   //creates an array of contacts of inital size 0

      this.contactViewer = new contactListFrame();
      contactViewer.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      this.contactGrid = new JPanel();
        contactGrid.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

      contactViewer.add(contactGrid);
      contactViewer.setVisible(true);
   }

   int checkList(String name)                                              //walks through the array checking for a contact of a specified name
   {
      if(contactList.length == 1)                                          //if the length of the contact list is one than its empty and an element should be added
      {
         return 1;
      }

      for(int i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++)
      {
         if(name.equals(contactList[i].getName()))
         {
            return 0;
         }
      }
      return 1;
   }

   void addContact(contact person)
   {                                                                       //calls check and if check returns true it adds the contact to the contactList
      if ( (checkList(person.getName())) > 0 )
      {
         resize(1);                                                        //calls resize method to increase the size of the array
         person.setID(contactCount++);                                     //gives the contact their id number
         contactList[contactList.length-1] = person;                       //adds the contact to the end of the array
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("ERROR, the requested contact is already in the list");
      }

   }

   void delete(int ID)                                                     //deletes a contact specified by name
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < contactList.length-1; i++)                        //runs through the array searching for the specified name
      {
         if(ID == contactList[i].getID())                                  //if the ID i was given matches the one im looking at in the
         {                                                                 //contact list AND i+1 does not equal the end of the array,
            contact temp = contactList[i];                                 //swap the entry marked for deletion with the next entry
            contactList[i] = contactList[i+1];                             //in the array until entry marked for deletion is at the end
            contactList[i+1] = temp;
         }
      }
      resize(-1);
   }

   void resize(int direction)
   {
      if(direction > 0)                                                    //if direction is a positive number increase the array size
      {
         contact[] tempList = new contact[contactList.length + 1];         //creates a temporary contact list array

         for(int i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++)                       //runs through the contact list array and copies its data into the temp list
         {
            tempList[i] = contactList[i];
         }

         contactList = new contact[contactList.length + 1];                //re initalizes contact list with a new size

         for(int i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++)                       //runs through the temp array and copies its data into the new bigger contact list
         {
            contactList[i] = tempList[i];
         }
      }
      else if(direction < 0)                                               //if direction is a negative number decrease the array size
      {
         contact[] tempList = new contact[contactList.length];             //creates a temporary contact list array

         for(int i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++)                       //runs through the contact list array and copies its data into the temp list
         {
            tempList[i] = contactList[i];
         }

         contactList = new contact[contactList.length - 1];                //re initalizes contact list with a new size

         for(int i = 0; i < contactList.length; i++)                       //runs through the contact list array and copies its data into the temp list
         {
            contactList[i] = tempList[i];
         }
      }
   }

   void sort()
   {

      for(int i = 0; i < contactList.length-1; i++)
      {
         for(int j = 1; j < contactList.length; j++)
         {
            if( (contactList[i].getName().charAt(0)) < (contactList[j].getName().charAt(0)) );
            {
               contact temp = contactList[i];
               contactList[i] = contactList[j];
               contactList[j] = temp;
            }
         }
      }
   }



   void showContacts()
   {
      JLabel contactInfo = new JLabel();


      for(int i = 0; i < contactList.length; i ++)
      {
         contactInfo.setText( getText(contactList[i]) );

         ImageIcon photo = new ImageIcon(getPicture(contactList[i]));
         contactInfo.setIcon(photo);

         contactGrid.add(contactInfo);
         contactGrid.setVisible(true);
      }

      contactViewer.add(contactGrid);
      //contactViewer.pack();
      contactViewer.setVisible(true);
   }









   String getPicture(contact person)
   {
      return (person.getPicture());
   }

   int getID(contact person)
   {
      return (person.getID());
   }

   String getName(contact person)
   {
      return (person.getName());
   }

   int getAddress(contact person)
   {
      return (person.getAddress());
   }

   String getCity(contact person)
   {
      return (person.getCity());
   }

   String getState(contact person)
   {
      return (person.getState());
   }

   int getZipCode(contact person)
   {
      return (person.getZipCode());
   }

   String getComment(contact person)
   {
      return (person.getComment());
   }

   String getText(contact person)
   {
      String text = Integer.toString(getID(person)) + " \n " + getName(person) + " \n " + Integer.toString(getAddress(person)) + " \n " + getCity(person) + " \n " + getState(person) + " \n " + Integer.toString(getZipCode(person)) + " \n " + getComment(person);
      return(text);
   }
}

}
```

Comment: I believe you misunderstood. What I was trying to do was get my contacts to display in a jframe. When i run the program the contacts appear but only if in the main method i call my show function every time a new contact is added. otherwise the jframe only shows the last contact added until the program is told which contact to delete. then the jframe displays too many contacts.